# Why Docusign JWT token - obtaining individual consent is not a direct option in account itself like revoke?

Tags: docusignapi

I have been setting up code to fetch JWT access token from docusign for our springboot app. By doing so, it requires getting consent from individual through redirect uri. But revoke is a direct option under connected apps.

1) why there is no direct option/link in account itself to get individual consent like revoke?

2) so if i nod consent once, any number our internal applications using same docusign account can get token without getting consent each time?

3)Tried creating organization using my sandbox account, after that for my app, granted administrative consent to both the signature and impersonation scopes. But I am unable to get token,  no consent error comes.(Used same email)

Thanks,
Karuna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers:

1. It is the app developer's responsibility to obtain consent. This is OAuth flow you would see in many other APIs/services. A future feature of an "app store" could make it possible for users to find apps and ask to use them, but that's not something that exists or is planned.
2. yes
3. Might need to see your code, see what scopes you are asking, what is the error message. Many more details needed to answer #3. That could be a general JWT issue, like private RSA key, userID etc. but I cannot know without more information.

Comment: Thanks Inbar. ques 3#, Its a sandbox account with my gmail id, i have given administrative consent to the 'signature impersonation' scopes. But when i accessed through my same gmail using our api code, Consent_missing error received. Could be the solution given by Larry below.

Comment: I thought you just tried to give consent to the one user for now just to see that working.
But yes, if you want admin/org level - you need to create a domain etc.

Comment: Hi Inbar, If I have some 3 apps/integration keys configured in my docusign account, Could i access envelopes across apps/integrations like getting status of envelope, created by another app/integration key

Answer (score 0):

> 1) why there is no direct option/link in account itself to get individual consent like revoke?

From a UX (user experience) point of view, we don't want users to have to type in any integration keys. And users can't choose an integration key from a list since integration keys are semi-secret information, they're not broadcast to users who don't need them.

So the right answer (for individual consent) is for the app developer to give each user a url that they can use to grant consent. And that's what we recommend. Note that the url can redirect to your company's home page or to a page that just says "Please close your tab."

> 2) so if i nod consent once, any number our internal applications using same docusign account can get token without getting consent each time?

Almost: once a user grants consent (to an integration key), then thereafter any app using that integration key (with access to one of the key's RSA's private keys) can impersonate that user in any account.

> 3)Tried creating organization using my sandbox account, after that for my app, granted administrative consent to both the signature and impersonation scopes. But I am unable to get token, no consent error comes. (Used same email)

Did you first claim the email domain used by the users? That step is also needed to grant consent administratively. (The docs certainly could be better. The docs group is working on an update.)

Comment: Hi Larry, If I have some 3 apps/integration keys configured in my docusign account, Could i access envelopes across apps/integrations like getting status of envelope, created by another app/integration key.